# Where (and by whom) should this exception be caught?

Tags: python, bottle

I have a very simple API server built on top of `bottle`. What is does is to just return a JSON upon being called, the content of the JSON being a random string. It works great.

This server was scanned yesterday by a vulnerability scanner (`nessus`) and crashed because of a misbehavior of the scanner. I include the Traceback information below which shows a `error: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host` exception.

My question is the following: who is the one who should handle this problem?

- Is this `nessus`, which does unholy things? On the one hand yes, it should behave in a standard way (this is a scanner which, among others, is used for industrial scans where it meets all sorts of devices and should attempt to mitigate the risk of crashes). On the other hand life is brutal and the receiving end (what is scanned) should be able to cope.
- Is this `bottle` ? It is a framework which should handle typical and not so typical web traffic and leave to the programmer the task of handling the business logic and not the internals
- Is this me? handling all the possible exceptions

I am asking as I would like to help improve either `nessus` or `bottle` (or myself) - this is not strictly a programming problem ("how to catch the exception") so if you really feel so, vote to close as opinion-based, though I ask anyway as I see it as a "programmers methodology" question.

The error stack:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Users/yop/Documents/dev/infoscreen/webserver.py
10.81.163.129 - - [03/Feb/2015 18:21:00] code 400, message Bad request syntax ('\x16\x03\x01\x00\xea\x01\x00\x00\xe6\x03\x01T\xd1\x03|\xb3\x02lm\xf0\xb92\x9a\xd7\xa7\xec\xbca\xdaR9\xfc\xe3]);`\xfbI\x98\x17\x94\xe3\x00\x00x\xc0\x14\xc0')
10.81.163.129 - - [03/Feb/2015 18:21:05] code 400, message Bad HTTP/0.9 request type ('\x16\x03\x01\x00\xea\x01\x00\x00\xe6\x03\x01T\xd1\x03\x81\xfcxI\x0e\xd5\xc4\xba\x17\xd9\x92\x9f+\x83BR\x10\x94N\xa5\x12\xc0')
10.81.163.129 - - [03/Feb/2015 18:21:24] code 400, message Bad request version ('Secure-HTTP/1.4')
10.81.163.129 - - [03/Feb/2015 18:21:24] code 400, message Bad request syntax ("\x16\x03\x01\x00\xea\x01\x00\x00\xe6\x03\x01T\xd1\x03\x95\x95\x154\x94h/5\x8dL\xa6\x148\x04#s\x13\x9f'\xec\x1az\xbc\x87/L\x0e\xc7\x02\x00\x00x\xc0\x14\xc0")
Traceback (most recent call last):
----------------------------------------
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 295, in _handle_request_noblock
Exception happened during processing of request from ('10.81.163.129', 57035)
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 321, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 651, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 117, in handle
    if not self.parse_request(): # An error code has been sent, just exit
  File "C:\Python27\lib\BaseHTTPServer.py", line 291, in parse_request
    self.headers = self.MessageClass(self.rfile, 0)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\mimetools.py", line 25, in __init__
----------------------------------------
    rfc822.Message.__init__(self, fp, seekable)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\rfc822.py", line 108, in __init__
    self.readheaders()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\rfc822.py", line 155, in readheaders
    line = self.fp.readline()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 447, in readline
    data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
error: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
Traceback (most recent call last):
----------------------------------------
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 295, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
Exception happened during processing of request from ('10.81.163.129', 37539)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 321, in process_request
----------------------------------------
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 651, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 116, in handle
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 447, in readline
    data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
error: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
----------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
Exception happened during processing of request from ('10.81.163.129', 38322)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 295, in _handle_request_noblock
----------------------------------------
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 321, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 651, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 116, in handle
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 447, in readline
    data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
error: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Process finished with exit code -1
```